# webiopi write to log when button is pushed

Tags: python, webiopi

Trying to learn the webiopi and python. I have a simple button to turn off and on a relay. Here is the HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>WebIOPi | Example App</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/webiopi.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        webiopi().ready(function() {

                // Create a "Light" labeled button for GPIO 17
                var light_button = webiopi().createGPIOButton(17, "Light", function() {
                    // Call the logtofile macro 
                    webiopi().callMacro("logtofile", [], '');
                });

                // Append buttons to HTML element with ID="controls" using jQuery
                $("#controls").append(light_button);

                // Refresh GPIO buttons
                // pass true to refresh repeatedly of false to refresh once
                webiopi().refreshGPIO(true);
        });

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
                button {
                        display: block;
                        margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
                        width: 160px;
                        height: 45px;
                        font-size: 24pt;
                        font-weight: bold;
                        color: white;
                }

                #gpio17.LOW {
                        background-color: Black;
                }

                #gpio17.HIGH {
                        background-color: Blue;
                }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="controls" align="center"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Straight forward stuff you will find in the tutorials around the web. I added this

```
// Call the logtofile macro 
webiopi().callMacro("logtofile", [], '');
```

To call a macro. My script file looks like this

```
import webiopi

GPIO = webiopi.GPIO

BLUE = 17 # GPIO pin using BCM numbering(BOARD 11)
RED = 18 # GPIO pin using BCM numbering(BOARD 12)
GREEN = 27 # GPIO pin using BCM numbering(BOARD 13)

# setup function is automatically called at WebIOPi startup
def setup():
    # set the GPIO used by the light to output
    GPIO.setFunction(BLUE, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setFunction(RED, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setFunction(GREEN, GPIO.OUT)

# loop function is repeatedly called by WebIOPi 
def loop():
    # gives CPU some time before looping again
    webiopi.sleep(1)

# destroy function is called at WebIOPi shutdown
def destroy():
    GPIO.digitalWrite(BLUE, GPIO.LOW)

@webiopi.macro
def logtofile():
    call([" sudo python /home/pi/buttonlog.py "], shell=False)
```

My logtofile macro is just calling the `/home/pi/buttonlog.py` that looks like this.

```
import datetime
i = datetime.datetime.now()

#OPEN FILE & APPEND
f=open('/home/pi/buttonlog.txt','a')
#WRITE DATE THEN NEW LINE WITH THE '\N'
f.write(i.isoformat() + '\n')
```

Straight forward code that writes the date to the `/home/pi/buttonlog.txt` However when I click the button I do not get the script to add the date to the file. If I run the `buttonlog.py` all by itself it writes to the file as expected. Am I missing something? I know this is probably not the simplest way to accomplish this but I am trying to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the f.close() command that actually syncs the change to the file system.